# Action Overflow on devices with menu key, like in new Google + app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, google-plus, actionbarsherlock

Googles new Google + and Google + Messenger has the action overflow item in the action bar on devices with menu key ( atleast on the galaxy s2 with ice cream that I have). Yet It seems like I can't force the overflow item on the action bar in my own app for these devices. Has Googled changed their mind about action overflow on devices with menu key? Does anyone know if it now is possible to add the overflow Item? ActionbarSherlock does not count as it does not work on Ice Cream devices..

Comment: ActionBarSherlock most certainly does work on ICS devices, insofar as it passes all requests along to the native implementation of the action bar.

Comment: Im talking about ABS in the context of the question.. It does not help with forcing the action overflow item on ICS devices with menu key. "There is no way to control the presence of the overflow action item on Android 4.0 and newer. The force overflow will ONLY affect 2.x and 3.x." - abs website. Im basically wondering if there is a way now, since Googles started doing it. My main concern is Galaxy s2/s3 devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use their own action bar implementation which looks exactly like the native version but allows them to use the ribbon menu. This is how they were able to always display an overflow.

This cannot be done with ActionBarSherlock using the native action bar.